# Ping Connection Pool Failed for JDBC Connection Pool

Tags: java, jdbc, database-connection

When tried to ping JDBC Connection Pool got error that Ping Connection Pool failed:

```
Connection could not be allocated because:  Connection authentication failure occurred.  Reason:  Userid or password invalid.  Userid and password are both set to APP.
```

Comment: You appear to have pasted an error message, but didn't actually ask a question about it. We cannot help you if you don't tell us what you need help with. By the way, the error message seems very descriptive and you probably should read it - the answer you are looking for might be there!

Comment: Why would a username and password of APP be invalid?  I followed the instructions for setting up the pool from the Deitel and Deitel How to Program Edition 9 Chapter 30.  And they said to define the username and password to be APP.

Answer (score 0):

To authenticate to the database, you must supply credentials that match an existing user in the database. So, first create the username and password in the database and then use the exact same values when you configure your connections.

The username and password can be pretty much any values. The important thing is that the values you specify when you connect to the database must exactly match the values that are set in the database.

To establish a username and password in the database use a command like:

```
CREATE USER 'username'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'password';
```

You will replace 'username' with the desired username (in this case 'APP') and replace 'password' with the desired password (in this case 'APP').